# Logical Displays in Linux?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors

Is there a way to section off one of my displays to make it behave like two displays?  I use multiple workspaces a lot, but I also like the functionality of another monitor, but I don't actually require the space of another monitor.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into tiling window managers like dwm.

Instead of having floating windows, like more conventional window managers, they split the screen into sections and allow you to set up your window layout very easily and efficiently.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager

The most common tiling window managers are dwm, xmonad and awesome